# iads.h / VS2005 / W2003 SP2 - which SDK and what are the side-effects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, sdk

I'm trying to compile someone elses C++ program using VS2005 on Windows 2003 (SP2).

The compile fails because it can't find iads.h

Which SDK should I install to get this header ?

When I install the SDK is there a danger I might break something already in use ? As far as I can tell the W2003 has no SDK's installed but if it did would installing a different one cause problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to the windows sdk. The SDK doesn't install like a regular application. Just because you "installed" it it doesn't change any settings in your compiler.

You will still have to add the directories to header files and libraries in the vs settings page.

You can have multiple version of the windows sdk, you just need to update the directories in the vs options page.

Comment: That's great thanks. From your description it sounds like I could 'install' it anywhere on the machine - is that so ? It's just the C: drive is *very* full. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can install it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

It should be found in the `vc\PlatformSDK\include` folder. If not then you need to check your installation or you can install the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The normal Windows SDK includes `<iads.h>`. I virtually never run a copy of Windows *without* an SDK installed, so I'm probably not in a good position to say what might work differently if it wasn't, but not much seems broken to me...